# c# LOESS/LOWESS regression

Tags: c#, regression

Do you know of a .net library to perform a LOESS/LOWESS regression? (preferably free/open source)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Port from [java](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.0/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/interpolation/LoessInterpolator.html) to c#

```
public class LoessInterpolator
{
    public static double DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH = 0.3;
    public static int DEFAULT_ROBUSTNESS_ITERS = 2;

    /**
     * The bandwidth parameter: when computing the loess fit at
     * a particular point, this fraction of source points closest
     * to the current point is taken into account for computing
     * a least-squares regression.
     * 
     * A sensible value is usually 0.25 to 0.5.
     */
    private double bandwidth;

    /**
     * The number of robustness iterations parameter: this many
     * robustness iterations are done.
     * 
     * A sensible value is usually 0 (just the initial fit without any
     * robustness iterations) to 4.
     */
    private int robustnessIters;

    public LoessInterpolator()
    {
        this.bandwidth = DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH;
        this.robustnessIters = DEFAULT_ROBUSTNESS_ITERS;
    }

    public LoessInterpolator(double bandwidth, int robustnessIters)
    {
        if (bandwidth < 0 || bandwidth > 1)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("bandwidth must be in the interval [0,1], but got {0}", bandwidth));
        }
        this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
        if (robustnessIters < 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("the number of robustness iterations must be non-negative, but got {0}", robustnessIters));
        }
        this.robustnessIters = robustnessIters;
    }

    /**
     * Compute a loess fit on the data at the original abscissae.
     *
     * @param xval the arguments for the interpolation points
     * @param yval the values for the interpolation points
     * @return values of the loess fit at corresponding original abscissae
     * @throws MathException if some of the following conditions are false:
     * <ul>
     * <li> Arguments and values are of the same size that is greater than zero</li>
     * <li> The arguments are in a strictly increasing order</li>
     * <li> All arguments and values are finite real numbers</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public double[] smooth(double[] xval, double[] yval)
    {
        if (xval.Length != yval.Length)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Loess expects the abscissa and ordinate arrays to be of the same size, but got {0} abscisssae and {1} ordinatae", xval.Length, yval.Length));
        }
        int n = xval.Length;
        if (n == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Loess expects at least 1 point");
        }

        checkAllFiniteReal(xval, true);
        checkAllFiniteReal(yval, false);
        checkStrictlyIncreasing(xval);

        if (n == 1)
        {
            return new double[] { yval[0] };
        }

        if (n == 2)
        {
            return new double[] { yval[0], yval[1] };
        }

        int bandwidthInPoints = (int)(bandwidth * n);

        if (bandwidthInPoints < 2)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("the bandwidth must be large enough to accomodate at least 2 points. There are {0} " +
                " data points, and bandwidth must be at least {1} but it is only {2}",
                n, 2.0 / n, bandwidth
            ));
        }

        double[] res = new double[n];

        double[] residuals = new double[n];
        double[] sortedResiduals = new double[n];

        double[] robustnessWeights = new double[n];

        // Do an initial fit and 'robustnessIters' robustness iterations.
        // This is equivalent to doing 'robustnessIters+1' robustness iterations
        // starting with all robustness weights set to 1.
        for (int i = 0; i < robustnessWeights.Length; i++) robustnessWeights[i] = 1;
        for (int iter = 0; iter <= robustnessIters; ++iter)
        {
            int[] bandwidthInterval = { 0, bandwidthInPoints - 1 };
            // At each x, compute a local weighted linear regression
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                double x = xval[i];

                // Find out the interval of source points on which
                // a regression is to be made.
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    updateBandwidthInterval(xval, i, bandwidthInterval);
                }

                int ileft = bandwidthInterval[0];
                int iright = bandwidthInterval[1];

                // Compute the point of the bandwidth interval that is
                // farthest from x
                int edge;
                if (xval[i] - xval[ileft] > xval[iright] - xval[i])
                {
                    edge = ileft;
                }
                else
                {
                    edge = iright;
                }

                // Compute a least-squares linear fit weighted by
                // the product of robustness weights and the tricube
                // weight function.
                // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression
                // (section "Univariate linear case")
                // and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares
                // (section "Weighted least squares")
                double sumWeights = 0;
                double sumX = 0, sumXSquared = 0, sumY = 0, sumXY = 0;
                double denom = Math.Abs(1.0 / (xval[edge] - x));
                for (int k = ileft; k <= iright; ++k)
                {
                    double xk = xval[k];
                    double yk = yval[k];
                    double dist;
                    if (k < i)
                    {
                        dist = (x - xk);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dist = (xk - x);
                    }
                    double w = tricube(dist * denom) * robustnessWeights[k];
                    double xkw = xk * w;
                    sumWeights += w;
                    sumX += xkw;
                    sumXSquared += xk * xkw;
                    sumY += yk * w;
                    sumXY += yk * xkw;
                }

                double meanX = sumX / sumWeights;
                double meanY = sumY / sumWeights;
                double meanXY = sumXY / sumWeights;
                double meanXSquared = sumXSquared / sumWeights;

                double beta;
                if (meanXSquared == meanX * meanX)
                {
                    beta = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    beta = (meanXY - meanX * meanY) / (meanXSquared - meanX * meanX);
                }

                double alpha = meanY - beta * meanX;

                res[i] = beta * x + alpha;
                residuals[i] = Math.Abs(yval[i] - res[i]);
            }

            // No need to recompute the robustness weights at the last
            // iteration, they won't be needed anymore
            if (iter == robustnessIters)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Recompute the robustness weights.

            // Find the median residual.
            // An arraycopy and a sort are completely tractable here, 
            // because the preceding loop is a lot more expensive
            System.Array.Copy(residuals, sortedResiduals, n);
            //System.arraycopy(residuals, 0, sortedResiduals, 0, n);
            Array.Sort<double>(sortedResiduals);
            double medianResidual = sortedResiduals[n / 2];

            if (medianResidual == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                double arg = residuals[i] / (6 * medianResidual);
                robustnessWeights[i] = (arg >= 1) ? 0 : Math.Pow(1 - arg * arg, 2);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Given an index interval into xval that embraces a certain number of
     * points closest to xval[i-1], update the interval so that it embraces
     * the same number of points closest to xval[i]
     *
     * @param xval arguments array
     * @param i the index around which the new interval should be computed
     * @param bandwidthInterval a two-element array {left, right} such that: <p/>
     * <tt>(left==0 or xval[i] - xval[left-1] > xval[right] - xval[i])</tt>
     * <p/> and also <p/>
     * <tt>(right==xval.length-1 or xval[right+1] - xval[i] > xval[i] - xval[left])</tt>.
     * The array will be updated.
     */
    private static void updateBandwidthInterval(double[] xval, int i, int[] bandwidthInterval)
    {
        int left = bandwidthInterval[0];
        int right = bandwidthInterval[1];

        // The right edge should be adjusted if the next point to the right
        // is closer to xval[i] than the leftmost point of the current interval
        int nextRight = nextNonzero(weights, right);
        if (nextRight < xval.Length && xval[nextRight] - xval[i] < xval[i] - xval[left])
        {
            int nextLeft = nextNonzero(weights, bandwidthInterval[0]);
            bandwidthInterval[0] = nextLeft;
            bandwidthInterval[1] = nextRight;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compute the 
     * <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression#Weight_function">tricube</a>
     * weight function
     *
     * @param x the argument
     * @return (1-|x|^3)^3
     */
    private static double tricube(double x)
    {
        double tmp = Math.abs(x);
               tmp = 1 - tmp * tmp * tmp;
        return tmp * tmp * tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Check that all elements of an array are finite real numbers.
     *
     * @param values the values array
     * @param isAbscissae if true, elements are abscissae otherwise they are ordinatae
     * @throws MathException if one of the values is not
     *         a finite real number
     */
    private static void checkAllFiniteReal(double[] values, bool isAbscissae)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            double x = values[i];
            if (Double.IsInfinity(x) || Double.IsNaN(x))
            {
                string pattern = isAbscissae ?
                        "all abscissae must be finite real numbers, but {0}-th is {1}" :
                        "all ordinatae must be finite real numbers, but {0}-th is {1}";
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(pattern, i, x));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check that elements of the abscissae array are in a strictly
     * increasing order.
     *
     * @param xval the abscissae array
     * @throws MathException if the abscissae array
     * is not in a strictly increasing order
     */
    private static void checkStrictlyIncreasing(double[] xval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < xval.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i >= 1 && xval[i - 1] >= xval[i])
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(
                        "the abscissae array must be sorted in a strictly " +
                        "increasing order, but the {0}-th element is {1} " +
                        "whereas {2}-th is {3}",
                        i - 1, xval[i - 1], i, xval[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed `updateBandwidthInterval()` and `tricube()`, but overall, anyone looking at this answer should consider checking  the current `commons.math3` implementation. This is old and buggy.

Comment: nextNonzero method is missing, can you provide it too?

Comment: after 2 years, nextNonzero is still missing

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm unable to comment on other people's posts (new user), and people seem to think I should do that with this instead of editing the above answer, I'm simply going to write it as an answer even though I know this is better as a comment.

The updateBandwidthInterval method in the above answer forgets to check the left side as written in the method comment. This can give NaN issues for sumWeights. The below should fix that. I encountered this when doing a c++ implementation based on the above.

```
 /**
 * Given an index interval into xval that embraces a certain number of
 * points closest to xval[i-1], update the interval so that it embraces
 * the same number of points closest to xval[i]
 *
 * @param xval arguments array
 * @param i the index around which the new interval should be computed
 * @param bandwidthInterval a two-element array {left, right} such that: <p/>
 * <tt>(left==0 or xval[i] - xval[left-1] > xval[right] - xval[i])</tt>
 * <p/> and also <p/>
 * <tt>(right==xval.length-1 or xval[right+1] - xval[i] > xval[i] - xval[left])</tt>.
 * The array will be updated.
 */
private static void updateBandwidthInterval(double[] xval, int i, int[] bandwidthInterval)
{
    int left = bandwidthInterval[0];
    int right = bandwidthInterval[1]; 

    // The edges should be adjusted if the previous point to the
    // left is closer to x than the current point to the right or
    // if the next point to the right is closer
    // to x than the leftmost point of the current interval
    if (left != 0 &&
       xval[i] - xval[left - 1] < xval[right] - xval[i])
    {
        bandwidthInterval[0]++;
        bandwidthInterval[1]++;
    }
    else if (right < xval.Length - 1 &&
       xval[right + 1] - xval[i] < xval[i] - xval[left])
    {
        bandwidthInterval[0]++;
        bandwidthInterval[1]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: From my tests this change is introducing important behavior change, which is suspicious

Answer (score 3):

Hope someone after 5 years find this useful. This is the original code posted by Tutcugil but with the missing methods and updated.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StockCorrelation
{
    public class LoessInterpolator
    {
        public static double DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH = 0.3;
        public static int DEFAULT_ROBUSTNESS_ITERS = 2;

        /**
         * The bandwidth parameter: when computing the loess fit at
         * a particular point, this fraction of source points closest
         * to the current point is taken into account for computing
         * a least-squares regression.
         * 
         * A sensible value is usually 0.25 to 0.5.
         */
        private double bandwidth;

        /**
         * The number of robustness iterations parameter: this many
         * robustness iterations are done.
         * 
         * A sensible value is usually 0 (just the initial fit without any
         * robustness iterations) to 4.
         */
        private int robustnessIters;

        public LoessInterpolator()
        {
            this.bandwidth = DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH;
            this.robustnessIters = DEFAULT_ROBUSTNESS_ITERS;
        }

        public LoessInterpolator(double bandwidth, int robustnessIters)
        {
            if (bandwidth < 0 || bandwidth > 1)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("bandwidth must be in the interval [0,1], but got {0}", bandwidth));
            }
            this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
            if (robustnessIters < 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("the number of robustness iterations must be non-negative, but got {0}", robustnessIters));
            }
            this.robustnessIters = robustnessIters;
        }

        /**
         * Compute a loess fit on the data at the original abscissae.
         *
         * @param xval the arguments for the interpolation points
         * @param yval the values for the interpolation points
         * @return values of the loess fit at corresponding original abscissae
         * @throws MathException if some of the following conditions are false:
         * <ul>
         * <li> Arguments and values are of the same size that is greater than zero</li>
         * <li> The arguments are in a strictly increasing order</li>
         * <li> All arguments and values are finite real numbers</li>
         * </ul>
         */
        public double[] smooth(double[] xval, double[] yval, double[] weights)
        {
            if (xval.Length != yval.Length)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Loess expects the abscissa and ordinate arrays to be of the same size, but got {0} abscisssae and {1} ordinatae", xval.Length, yval.Length));
            }
            int n = xval.Length;
            if (n == 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Loess expects at least 1 point");
            }

            checkAllFiniteReal(xval, true);
            checkAllFiniteReal(yval, false);
            checkStrictlyIncreasing(xval);

            if (n == 1)
            {
                return new double[] { yval[0] };
            }

            if (n == 2)
            {
                return new double[] { yval[0], yval[1] };
            }

            int bandwidthInPoints = (int)(bandwidth * n);

            if (bandwidthInPoints < 2)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("the bandwidth must be large enough to accomodate at least 2 points. There are {0} " +
                    " data points, and bandwidth must be at least {1} but it is only {2}",
                    n, 2.0 / n, bandwidth
                ));
            }

            double[] res = new double[n];

            double[] residuals = new double[n];
            double[] sortedResiduals = new double[n];

            double[] robustnessWeights = new double[n];

            // Do an initial fit and 'robustnessIters' robustness iterations.
            // This is equivalent to doing 'robustnessIters+1' robustness iterations
            // starting with all robustness weights set to 1.
            for (int i = 0; i < robustnessWeights.Length; i++) robustnessWeights[i] = 1;
            for (int iter = 0; iter <= robustnessIters; ++iter)
            {
                int[] bandwidthInterval = { 0, bandwidthInPoints - 1 };
                // At each x, compute a local weighted linear regression
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    double x = xval[i];

                    // Find out the interval of source points on which
                    // a regression is to be made.
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        updateBandwidthInterval(xval, weights, i, bandwidthInterval);
                    }

                    int ileft = bandwidthInterval[0];
                    int iright = bandwidthInterval[1];

                    // Compute the point of the bandwidth interval that is
                    // farthest from x
                    int edge;
                    if (xval[i] - xval[ileft] > xval[iright] - xval[i])
                    {
                        edge = ileft;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edge = iright;
                    }

                    // Compute a least-squares linear fit weighted by
                    // the product of robustness weights and the tricube
                    // weight function.
                    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression
                    // (section "Univariate linear case")
                    // and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares
                    // (section "Weighted least squares")
                    double sumWeights = 0;
                    double sumX = 0, sumXSquared = 0, sumY = 0, sumXY = 0;
                    double denom = Math.Abs(1.0 / (xval[edge] - x));
                    for (int k = ileft; k <= iright; ++k)
                    {
                        double xk = xval[k];
                        double yk = yval[k];
                        double dist;
                        if (k < i)
                        {
                            dist = (x - xk);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dist = (xk - x);
                        }
                        double w = tricube(dist * denom) * robustnessWeights[k];
                        double xkw = xk * w;
                        sumWeights += w;
                        sumX += xkw;
                        sumXSquared += xk * xkw;
                        sumY += yk * w;
                        sumXY += yk * xkw;
                    }

                    double meanX = sumX / sumWeights;
                    double meanY = sumY / sumWeights;
                    double meanXY = sumXY / sumWeights;
                    double meanXSquared = sumXSquared / sumWeights;

                    double beta;
                    if (meanXSquared == meanX * meanX)
                    {
                        beta = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        beta = (meanXY - meanX * meanY) / (meanXSquared - meanX * meanX);
                    }

                    double alpha = meanY - beta * meanX;

                    res[i] = beta * x + alpha;
                    residuals[i] = Math.Abs(yval[i] - res[i]);
                }

                // No need to recompute the robustness weights at the last
                // iteration, they won't be needed anymore
                if (iter == robustnessIters)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Recompute the robustness weights.

                // Find the median residual.
                // An arraycopy and a sort are completely tractable here, 
                // because the preceding loop is a lot more expensive
                System.Array.Copy(residuals, sortedResiduals, n);
                //System.arraycopy(residuals, 0, sortedResiduals, 0, n);
                Array.Sort<double>(sortedResiduals);
                double medianResidual = sortedResiduals[n / 2];

                if (medianResidual == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    double arg = residuals[i] / (6 * medianResidual);
                    robustnessWeights[i] = (arg >= 1) ? 0 : Math.Pow(1 - arg * arg, 2);
                }
            }

            return res;
        }

        public double[] smooth(double[] xval, double[] yval)
        {
            if (xval.Length != yval.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception($"xval and yval len are different");
            }

            double[] unitWeights = Enumerable.Repeat(1.0, xval.Length).ToArray();

            return smooth(xval, yval, unitWeights);
        }

        /**
         * Given an index interval into xval that embraces a certain number of
         * points closest to xval[i-1], update the interval so that it embraces
         * the same number of points closest to xval[i]
         *
         * @param xval arguments array
         * @param i the index around which the new interval should be computed
         * @param bandwidthInterval a two-element array {left, right} such that: <p/>
         * <tt>(left==0 or xval[i] - xval[left-1] > xval[right] - xval[i])</tt>
         * <p/> and also <p/>
         * <tt>(right==xval.length-1 or xval[right+1] - xval[i] > xval[i] - xval[left])</tt>.
         * The array will be updated.
         */
        private static void updateBandwidthInterval(double[] xval, double[] weights,
                                                            int i,
                                                            int[] bandwidthInterval)
        {
            int left = bandwidthInterval[0];
            int right = bandwidthInterval[1];

            // The right edge should be adjusted if the next point to the right
            // is closer to xval[i] than the leftmost point of the current interval
            int nextRight = nextNonzero(weights, right);
            if (nextRight < xval.Length && xval[nextRight] - xval[i] < xval[i] - xval[left])
            {
                int nextLeft = nextNonzero(weights, bandwidthInterval[0]);
                bandwidthInterval[0] = nextLeft;
                bandwidthInterval[1] = nextRight;
            }
        }

        private static int nextNonzero(double[] weights, int i)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (j < weights.Length && weights[j] == 0)
            {
                ++j;
            }
            return j;
        }

        /**
         * Compute the 
         * <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression#Weight_function">tricube</a>
         * weight function
         *
         * @param x the argument
         * @return (1-|x|^3)^3
         */
        private static double tricube(double x)
        {
            double tmp = Math.Abs(x);
            tmp = 1 - tmp * tmp * tmp;
            return tmp * tmp * tmp;
        }

        /**
         * Check that all elements of an array are finite real numbers.
         *
         * @param values the values array
         * @param isAbscissae if true, elements are abscissae otherwise they are ordinatae
         * @throws MathException if one of the values is not
         *         a finite real number
         */
        private static void checkAllFiniteReal(double[] values, bool isAbscissae)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                double x = values[i];
                if (Double.IsInfinity(x) || Double.IsNaN(x))
                {
                    string pattern = isAbscissae ?
                            "all abscissae must be finite real numbers, but {0}-th is {1}" :
                            "all ordinatae must be finite real numbers, but {0}-th is {1}";
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(pattern, i, x));
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Check that elements of the abscissae array are in a strictly
         * increasing order.
         *
         * @param xval the abscissae array
         * @throws MathException if the abscissae array
         * is not in a strictly increasing order
         */
        private static void checkStrictlyIncreasing(double[] xval)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < xval.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (i >= 1 && xval[i - 1] >= xval[i])
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(
                            "the abscissae array must be sorted in a strictly " +
                            "increasing order, but the {0}-th element is {1} " +
                            "whereas {2}-th is {3}",
                            i - 1, xval[i - 1], i, xval[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```