# Loess implementation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regression

I am looking for a Javascript implementation of the LOESS regression algorithm.  I've seen plenty for R and a few other ones but not Javascript.

BTW I found this [C# Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651709/c-sharp-loess-lowess-regression) for LOESS but not JavaScript.  I guess it could be ported to Javascript ?

Comment: check this : https://gist.github.com/1151823#file_loess.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Google I found the following code right after your question: https://gist.github.com/avibryant/1151823

However, science.js seems like a more feature-rich implementation of all your smoothing needs: https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js

EDIT:

I've started to look more broadly at statistics packages for JS, and the following blog post actually wraps it up pretty nicely: http://jgoodall.me/posts/2012/02/01/javascript-statistical-libraries/

Obviously it's all a far cry from R (http://r-project.org), which web-wise has progressed from RApache (http://rapache.net/) to shiny (http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/). The latter uses node.js server-side, so this is quite promising. Of course both approaches will require you to code stats in R server-side, instead of using JS either on client or server.

EDIT2: Only now saw the original query answered via "comment" instead of "answer". Sorry!

EDIT3: Related SO post with interesting pointers: [Is there any statistical library for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656897/is-there-any-statistical-library-for-javascript)

Marc

Comment: New version: [github.com/chdh/commons-math-interpolation](https://github.com/chdh/commons-math-interpolation)